# How to sum array values,array was created from SQL query

Tags: php

I want to sum an associative array values.The array was created from SQL query.

I tried to sum with array_sum,but array sum was not worked because,my array is not a typical array ($array=array(1,2,3)).
Array_sum will return 0.

```
public function getAge(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['age_hold']) && !empty($_SESSION['age_hold']) ){
        $sqlAge="SELECT age FROM unisex 
        WHERE age >=".$_SESSION['age_hold'] ;
        $age= Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sqlAge)->queryAll();
        return $age;
    }
}


   $age=$this->getAge();
$length=count($age);





   $ageSummation=0;
  foreach($age as $key=>$item) {
  $ageSummation=$ageSummation+$item;
 }
```

Displaying $age array:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [age] => 90 ) [1] => Array ( [age] => 91 ) [2] => Array ( [age] => 92 ) [3] => Array ( [age] => 93 ) [4] => Array ( [age] => 94 ) [5] => Array ( [age] => 95 ) [6] => Array ( [age] => 96 ) [7] => Array ( [age] => 97 ) [8] => Array ( [age] => 98 ) [9] => Array ( [age] => 99 ) [10] => Array ( [age] => 100 ) )
```

When i run the code with that foreach, the error is "Unsupported operand types".

I expect to output to be 90+91+92+...+100

Comment: Why not `SELECT SUM(age) as ageSummation FROM unisex . . .`

Comment: You should not be building queries manually. You are vulnerable to SQL injection. Use [Yii query builder](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder)

Answer (score 2):

The items in `$age` are arrays, not integers. You're getting ""Unsupported operand types" because you're trying to add them to 0.

You can use array_column to sum the age key.

```
$ageSummation = array_sum(array_column($age, 'age'));
```

You could also do it in your query, unless you're going to use the individual values for something. I see you also have `$length=count($age);` in your code, which suggests you may be calculating an average age - you can do that in the query as well if you like.

```
SELECT AVG(age) FROM unisex WHERE age >= ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get all of the `age` values in the nested array:

`array_sum(array_column($age, 'age'))`

Or if you have other logic to apply in the loop, you could just use the `age` key in your existing code:

```
foreach($age as $item) 
    $ageSummation=$ageSummation+$item['age'];
```